# hierarchial two dimetional php array from an two dimetional php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, hierarchical-data

I have a multiD array containing all users like below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [username] => santoshe62
            [sponsor] => santoshe61
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [username] => santoshe63
            [sponsor] => santoshe62
        )
    [2] => Array
         (
            [username] => santoshe65
            [sponsor] => santoshe64
        )
    [3] => Array
         (
            [username] => santoshe67
            [sponsor] => santoshe66
        )
     .............................
)
```

I want an array from this array containing hierarchical data of given user like below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [username] => santoshe62
            [sponsor] => santoshe61
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [username] => santoshe63
            [sponsor] => santoshe62
        )

)
```

I have tried

```
function parseTree($datas, $parent = 0){
    $tree = array();
    for($i=0, $ni=count($datas); $i < $ni; $i++){
        if($datas[$i]['sponsor'] == $parent){
            $tree[] = $datas[$i];
            parseTree($datas, $datas[$i]['username']);
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

Can anybody help me by finding what is wrong in my code?  Also please suggest, can I select only this hierarchical structure directly from MySQL?  Now I am selecting all results from DB.

Comment: What do you mean by *I want an array from this array containing hierarchical data*? And what's the logic behind the second multidimensional array?

Comment: means array containing all the children , grand children, great grand so on ......... for any given username like the second given array for username 'santoshe61'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of this statement in your function, `$tree = array();`. In each recursive function call, this `$tree` is getting initialized with an empty array. You have to declare it as `static` variable, so that it could get initialized **only once** and could retain its state in recursive function calls.

```
function parseTree($datas, $parent = 0){
    static $tree = array();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanx buddy, can it be directly selected from MYSQL db with a query or procedure or it will be better than that?

Comment: @santosh I don't think this kind of (dynamic) hierarchical data can be generated just by using SQL query. However, you can directly construct this kind of array while iterating through the result set.